# Generating a 2-d array with iterations using Python

Tags: python, list

For example I have the following 2-d array

```
t = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5],
     [6,7]]
```

by using list comprehensions i get

```
>>> [[x, y, z] for x in t[2] for y in t[1] for z in t[0]]
[[6, 4, 1], 
 [6, 4, 2], 
 [6, 4, 3], 
 [6, 5, 1], 
 [6, 5, 2], 
 [6, 5, 3], 
 [7, 4, 1], 
 [7, 4, 2], 
 [7, 4, 3], 
 [7, 5, 1], 
 [7, 5, 2], 
 [7, 5, 3]]
```

But how if the inputs has more than 3 lists? I mean, I don't want hard codes the t[2], and something like that. I want to take *t* consisting any number of lists as input. Is there anyway using list comprehensions to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd take a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> t = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
>>> [x for x in itertools.product(*t[::-1])]
[(6, 4, 1),
 (6, 4, 2),
 (6, 4, 3),
 (6, 5, 1),
 (6, 5, 2),
 (6, 5, 3),
 (7, 4, 1),
 (7, 4, 2),
 (7, 4, 3),
 (7, 5, 1),
 (7, 5, 2),
 (7, 5, 3)]
>>> [list(x) for x in itertools.product(*t[::-1])]
[[6, 4, 1],
 [6, 4, 2],
 [6, 4, 3],
 [6, 5, 1],
 [6, 5, 2],
 [6, 5, 3],
 [7, 4, 1],
 [7, 4, 2],
 [7, 4, 3],
 [7, 5, 1],
 [7, 5, 2],
 [7, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: You beat me to it! =D

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: t = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]

In [3]: list(itertools.product(*t[::-1]))
Out[3]:
[(6, 4, 1),
 (6, 4, 2),
 (6, 4, 3),
 (6, 5, 1),
 (6, 5, 2),
 (6, 5, 3),
 (7, 4, 1),
 (7, 4, 2),
 (7, 4, 3),
 (7, 5, 1),
 (7, 5, 2),
 (7, 5, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the itertools module. The [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function does what you want, 
except you may want to reverse the input order.